# get null thrown parameter android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I try to pass 4 parameter from page4 class to page5 class. Before it, I already pass this 4 parameter on other 4 pages and it success get the parameter on the receiver page class. But problem happen when I throw parameter use intent from page4 class to page5 class.

here is the parameter that I throw :

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String region= extras.getString("REGION");
    final String tipepizza= extras.getString("PIZZA");
    final String pizzaname= extras.getString("PIZZA_NAME");
    final String pizzaprice= extras.getString("PIZZA_PRICE");
    final String pizzadesc= extras.getString("PIZZA_DESC");
    final String jumlah= extras.getString("JUMLAH");
    Utils.log("pizzaname3: " + pizzaname);
    Utils.log("pizzaprice3: " + pizzaprice);
    Utils.log("jumlah3: " + jumlah);
```

When I log on page4 class, I success get parameter pizzaname, pizzaprice, pizzadesc, jumlah,region, tipepizza from page3 class.

Then I throw parameter from page4 class to page5 class like this:

```
btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final String finalcounter = counter.getText().toString();
            final String finalprice = lblhargaatas.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Cart.class);
            intent.putExtra("REGION", region);
            intent.putExtra("PIZZA_NAME", pizzaname);
            intent.putExtra("PIZZA_PRICE", finalprice);
            intent.putExtra("JUMLAH", finalcounter);
            Utils.log("sent region: " + region);
            Utils.log("sent pizzaname: " + pizzaname);
            Utils.log("sent pizzaprice: " + finalprice);
            Utils.log("sent jumlah: " + finalcounter);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I just want to throw region, pizzaname, pizzaprice, finalcounter (from page4 class to page5 class). But when I log on page5 class I only get region.

pizzaname, pizzaprice, finalcounter result is null.

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String region= extras.getString("REGION");
    final String pizzaname= extras.getString("PIZZA_NAME");
    final String pizzaprice= extras.getString("PIZZA_PRICE");
    final String jumlah= extras.getString("JUMLAH");
    Utils.log("regionkumura: " + region);
    Utils.log("pizzaname: " + pizzaname);
    Utils.log("pizzaprice: " + pizzaprice);
    Utils.log("jumlah: " + jumlah);
```

How to correct throw parameter use intent to get it on page5 class?

Update: Sorry wrong button, it should be like this :

```
btnAddOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final String finalcounter = counter.getText().toString();
            final String finalprice = lblhargaatas.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Cart.class);
            intent.putExtra("REGION", region);
            intent.putExtra("PIZZA_NAME", pizzaname);
            intent.putExtra("PIZZA_PRICE", finalprice);
            intent.putExtra("JUMLAH", finalcounter);
            Utils.log("sent region: " + region);
            Utils.log("sent pizzaname: " + pizzaname);
            Utils.log("sent pizzaprice: " + finalprice);
            Utils.log("sent jumlah: " + finalcounter);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: **throw**; *you keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.*

Comment: sorry, my english is not good.

Comment: `throw` is a keyword that is used in the context of `Exceptions` within Java.

Comment: In the `onClick` method in your second example, can you try to log the value of pizza_name, pizza_price, etc. I have a feeling that you're passing null values which would mean that you're storing them incorrectly or retrieving them wrong.

Comment: final String finalcounter = counter.getText().toString();
 final String finalprice = lblhargaatas.getText().toString();
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, Cart.class);
 intent.putExtra("REGION", region);
 intent.putExtra("PIZZA_NAME", pizzaname);
 intent.putExtra("PIZZA_PRICE", finalprice);
 intent.putExtra("JUMLAH", finalcounter);
Utils.log("sent region: " + region);
Utils.log("sent pizzaname: " + pizzaname);
Utils.log("sent pizzaprice: " + finalprice);
Utils.log("sent jumlah: " + finalcounter);
startActivity(intent); , I got nothing on log

Comment: please do not post huge unreadble code chunks in the comments. Just edit your original question with the updated information please.

Comment: When you clicked the button, what exactly showed up in the log?

Comment: I updated the code on question (on onlick event). I got nothing on log, but I can get region on page5 class log.

Comment: When you say nothing showed up in the log, are you saying that even the text `"sent region"` didn't even show up as if the log command wasn't even called?

Comment: that log sent region did not show up.

Comment: well doesn't that sound like that entire method didn't get called? do you have another point in page4 class which can start the page5 activity?

Comment: it seems, I put in the wrong button, it should be btnaddorder not btncart. Thanks.

Comment: ill post a summary of our deduction as an answer so others can see this has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned that the logging information in the `page4` class wasn't displayed when the button was clicked there can only be a handful of reasons why the data isn't being passed.

1. You have the `onClick` listener on the wrong button
2. You have set the `onClick` listener to `null` later on

I imagine it's likely the first one.